# Missing mandatory element error in the uv4l streaming server

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, janus, janus-gateway

I'm trying to get the RPi streaming video to Janus server over the internet architecture.

Firstly, I have installed and configured the UV4L streaming server in the RPi zero, just like the linux project mentioned, and the ip:port/stream is working perfectly fine, and i can rtc the video in local network.
Now, I need the communication to happen over internet, so I have a janus server setup in the server.
In the RPi UV4L server, I first wanted to try the stream to the public Janus server first, so I tried doing it using the "Join the room with janus", but when I click start, I get logs

```
Oct 27 04:52:52 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [server] HTTP/HTTPS Streaming & WebRTC Signalling Server v1.1.125 built on Sep  5 2019
Oct 27 04:52:52 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <warning> [server] SSL is not enabled for the Streaming Server. Using unsecure HTTP.
Oct 27 04:52:52 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [core] Streaming Server loaded!
Oct 27 04:52:52 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <warning> [core] Cannot create /dev/video0 because file already exists
Oct 27 04:52:52 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [core] Registering device node /dev/video1
Oct 27 04:52:52 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [server] Web Streaming Server listening on port 8080
Oct 27 04:53:22 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [webrtc] WebRTC Renderer extension successfully loaded
Oct 27 04:53:22 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [server] WebRTC, Signalling Server and STUN Server extensions successfully loaded
Oct 27 04:53:26 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <warning> [server] Missing mandatory element (admin_key)
Oct 27 04:53:33 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <warning> [server] Janus session error: Missing mandatory element (admin_key)
Oct 27 04:53:33 DevIoT uv4l[7990]: <notice> [server] Waiting for 3 seconds before reconnecting to https://janus.conf.meetecho.com...
```

Please tell me how to resolve it? or What I'm doing wrong here? Or any alternative solutions, I need the RTC from rpi to a public server.